# Sequence of command?

Tags: java, android

I wrote this code

```
    WindowManager.LayoutParams params = getWindow().getAttributes();
    params.flags |= LayoutParams.FLAG_KEEP_SCREEN_ON;
    params.screenBrightness = 0.1F;
    getWindow().setAttributes(params);

    SystemClock.sleep(5000);

    TextView Text01 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.Text1);
    Text01.setText("Hello");
```

to set the screen brightness and then, after 5 seconds, it displays text. The problem is that it waits 5 secs then Android dims the screen and output the text at the same time. Why it does not work sequentially?
Thanks

Comment: It is Java for Android app - for mobile phone

Comment: OK - question now tagged appropriately - please take care with this in future.

Comment: possible duplicate: [repeat task in Android](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12220239/repeat-task-in-android)

Comment: Paul, this is the issue with sequence of task when using arbitrary delay but not the task repeating. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

My guess is that code is running in the UI thread, which means nothing gets drawn to the UI until your function exits. You might want to set up a callback of some kind to trigger the change of text in the future. Maybe an [AsyncTask](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html), where the sleeping happens in the background thread and the UI altering code happens in `onPostExecute`.

Comment: THanks, I think that is UI problem too. I have read a script at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10368919/why-imageview-cant-update-before-systemclock-sleep which has the same issue so I tried, it works. However I cannot extend to let arbitrary wait between commands, say 5-6 commands which need to change screen colour/brightness at different time delay. Do you have any idea to go through that?

Comment: Use a [Handler](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Handler.html). They have methods which allow for arbitrary delays, like `sendEmptyMessageDelayed`.

Comment: But can I have more than one Handler? as after each command i need one. Also the problem is UI does not allow update until the last command, so any technique to overcome this?