# Turn based android game - thread synchronisation

Tags: android, multithreading, synchronization, onclicklistener

Hie guys (better yet, coders),
I'v this use case :

open app > game starts with user's turn > He got to enter a country in Edittext & click on submit button before **20 seconds** else num_of_faults will increase by 1 (if(num_of_faults == 3) game_over)

now semi pseudo code is :

```
static void Game(){
    while(true){
        getTimedInput();
        while(true){        
            if(condition 1 is false){
                num_of_faults++;
                getTimedInput();
            } else {
                continue game;          
            }
            if(num_of_faults == max_tries){
                break;
            }
        }       
        if(num_of_faults == max_tries){
            return;
        }       
    }
}

public static void getTimedInput(){
    final Thread thread=  new Thread(){
        @Override
        public void run(){
            try {
                synchronized(this){
                    wait(20000);
                }
            }
            catch(InterruptedException ex){                    
            }
        }
    };
    thread.start();

   inputSubmit.setClickable(true);
   inputSubmit.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {           
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            synchronized(thread){
                thread.notifyAll();
            }
            get editText input some input validations..           

            if(condition 2 is false){ 
                inputSubmit.setClickable(false);
                inputSubmit.setOnClickListener(null);
                getTimedInput();
            } else if(condition 3 is false) {
                inputSubmit.setClickable(false);
                inputSubmit.setOnClickListener(null);
                getTimedInput();
            } else {
                continue game;
            }
        }
    });  
}
```

it indeed is possible duplicate of "waiting for user to click a button" on stack overflow,
But i'v spent many all nighters trying to solve this,
PS : can't really seem to put whole code in onClickListener, i'hd really appreciate if ne1 could really put some effort in solving abovmentioned logic, or at least give me some pointers to work upon.
Thanks!

Comment: You haven't actually said what your problem is...

Comment: Word of advice: learn how to use Handler, especially for posting delayed events in the UI thread (using postDelayed(...). There is a bunch of tutorials about this indeed on the net, and the key point is: you don't need a separate thread for a trivial task like this. See this as a starting point: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10368919/why-imageview-cant-update-before-systemclock-sleep/10368952#10368952

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Think you would be better using a more standard game loop.
Below is an example of how you might go about this.

```
public class Game extends Thread {

    private static final int START_SUBMIT_COUNTRY = 1;
    private static final int FINISH_SUBMIT_COUNTRY = 2;
    private static final int COUNTRY_SUBMIT_TIMEOUT = 3;

    private final long SUBMIT_TIMEOUT = 20 * 1000;

    private long countrySubmitBeginTime;
    private boolean isRunning = false;
    private boolean submitCountry = false;
    private Handler parentHandler;
    private final GameHandler gameHandler = new GameHandler(this);

    // Constructor
    public Game(Handler parentHandler) {
        this.parentHandler = parentHandler
    }

    public Handler getHandler() {
        return gameHandler:
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {

        long timeDiff;

        try {
            isRunning = true;
            while(isRunning) {
                ...
                if (submitCountry) {
                    timeDiff = System.currentTimeMillis() - countrySubmitBeginTime;
                    if (timeDiff > SUBMIT_TIMEOUT) {

                        // the timeout has expired so message the parent to let it know
                        Message message = Message.obtain();
                        message.what = COUNTRY_SUBMIT_TIMEOUT;
                        parentHandler.sendMessage(message);
                    }
                }
                ...

        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.e("Game", "Thread Loop Exception: " + e);
        }
    }

    // Method to start the submitting-a-country action
    private void startCountrySubmit() {
        submitCountry = true;
        countrySubmitBeginTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
    }

    // Method to end the submitting-a-country action
    private void startCountrySubmit() {
        submitCountry = false;
    }

    // Private Nested Class to handle messages to the thread
    private static class GameHandler extends Handler {

        private final WeakReference<Game> mGame;

        // Constructor
        public GameHandler(Game game) {
            mGame = new WeakReference<Game>(game);
        }

        @Override
        public void handleMessage(Message msg) {
            Game game = mGame.get();
            if (game != null) {
                switch (msg.what) {
                    case START_SUBMIT_COUNTRY:
                        game.startCountrySubmit();
                        break;
                    case FINISH_SUBMIT_COUNTRY:
                        game.finishCountrySubmit();
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

After you create and start a Game game thread in your main UI thread, you can send messages to it to tell it when to start timing a submit-country action by sending it a START_SUBMIT_COUNTRY message, and send it a FINISH_SUBMIT_COUNTRY message to tell it to stop timing (for example when a country is successfully entered). If the time limit expires before you send a FINISH_SUBMIT_COUNTRY message to the thread, it will notify your main UI thread with a COUNTRY_SUBMIT_TIMEOUT message.
There are quite a few concepts here, so you may need to do a bit of reading if any are new to you.

Comment: Thanks @soundC, marking it as accepted answer.
Though, could u explain, y did u use weakReference?

Comment: I used a WeakReference so we can call the outer classes methods without leaking a context. Leaking contexts is a whole topic on it's own. It's explained much better in this [blog post](http://www.androiddesignpatterns.com/2013/01/inner-class-handler-memory-leak.html) than I could, or have room for in this comment. The guy who wrote that blog now works at google, so I think he knows what he's on about. :)